Chrome Local Cookie storage decrypt fails Python
I am struggling to decrypt Chrome cookies in local storage on Windows. I used this code below that was working fine for me some time ago but now I am just getting the error:

decrypt.py", line 24, in decrypt_cookies
query_res = cursor.fetchall()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ sqlite3.OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'encrypted_value' with text

After googling this problem I tried to change text_factory:
conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)
conn.text_factory = bytes

But this leads to a new error:

Lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Cipher_mode_gcm.py", line 508, in verify
raise ValueError("MAC check failed") ValueError: MAC check failed

This is the whole code I used:
Decrypt module:
# decrypt.py
import argparse
import base64
import os
import sqlite3
import sys

from Cryptodome.Cipher.AES import new, MODE_GCM # pip install pycryptodomex
from win32.win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData # pip install pywin32

import encrypt

def decrypt_dpapi_blob(encrypted_blob):
    encrypted_blob = base64.b64decode(encrypted_blob)[5:]  # Leading bytes "DPAPI" need to be removed
    decrypt_res = CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_blob, None, None, None, 0)
    return decrypt_res


def decrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key):
    sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)
    conn.text_factory = bytes

    query = "SELECT name, encrypted_value FROM cookies"
    cursor = conn.execute(query)
    query_res = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in query_res:
        cookie_name, encrypted_value = row
        if encrypted_value is None or len(encrypted_value) == 0:
            continue

        verification_tag = encrypted_value[-16:]
        aes_cipher = new(key=key, mode=MODE_GCM, nonce=encrypted_value[3:15])
        decrypted_value = aes_cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext=encrypted_value[15: -16], received_mac_tag=verification_tag)
        # if cookie_name == "BITBUCKETSESSIONID":
        #     print(f"Decrypted cookie (bitbucket):\n  {decrypted_value.decode()}")
        #     print(f"Verification tag (bitbucket):\n  {bytes_to_hex(verification_tag)}")
        #     print(f"Nonce (bitbucket):\n  {bytes_to_hex(nonce)}")
        query = f"UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value = ? WHERE name = '{cookie_name}'"
        params = [decrypted_value]
        cursor.execute(query, params)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        decrypted_key = encrypt.get_local_state_key()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Decryption failed:", str(e))
        sys.exit(1)
    # C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network
    # Arg: cookies_db
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--cookies", help="Name of the cookies database file", default="Cookies")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    cookies_db = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), args.cookies)

    decrypt_cookies(cookies_db, decrypted_key)

Encrypt module:
#encrypt.py
import argparse
import json
import os
import base64
import sqlite3
from os.path import expandvars

from Cryptodome.Cipher.AES import new, MODE_GCM # pip install pycryptodomex
from win32.win32crypt import CryptProtectData # pip install pywin32

import decrypt


def encrypt_dpapi_blob(decrypted_blob):
    encrypted_blob = CryptProtectData(decrypted_blob, DataDescr="Google Chrome", OptionalEntropy=None, Reserved=None, PromptStruct=None, Flags=0)
    encrypted_blob = b'DPAPI' + encrypted_blob
    encrypted_blob_base64 = base64.b64encode(encrypted_blob)
    return encrypted_blob_base64


def encrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key):
    sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(cookies_db)

    query = "SELECT name, encrypted_value FROM cookies"
    cursor = conn.execute(query)
    query_res = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in query_res:
        cookie_name, decrypted_value = row
        if decrypted_value is None or len(decrypted_value) == 0:
            continue
        
        nonce = os.urandom(12)
        aes_cipher = new(key=key, mode=MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
        encrypted_value, verification_tag = aes_cipher.encrypt_and_digest(decrypted_value)

        encrypted_cookie = b'\x76\x31\x30' +\
            nonce +\
            encrypted_value +\
            verification_tag

        query = f"UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value = ? WHERE name = '{cookie_name}'"
        params = [encrypted_cookie]
        cursor.execute(query, params)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def get_local_state_key():
    local_state = json.load(open(expandvars('%LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/Chrome/User Data/Local State')))
    encrypted_key = local_state['os_crypt']['encrypted_key']
    decrypted_key = decrypt.decrypt_dpapi_blob(encrypted_key)[1]
    return decrypted_key


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Arg: cookies_db
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--cookies", help="Name of the cookies database file", default="Cookies")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    cookies_db = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), args.cookies)
    key = get_local_state_key()
    encrypt_cookies(cookies_db, key)

